# React Native - fetch doesn't seem to fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

Fetch doesn't seem to fire - this is my component in React Native:

```
import { Button } from 'react-native';

export function Test() {
  function submit() {
    console.log('submit');
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/').then(
      res => {
        console.log('res', res);
        return res.json();
      },
      err => console.log('err', err)
    ).then(
      res => console.log('res', res)
    ).catch(
      err => console.log('catch', err)
    ).finally(
      res => console.log('finally', res)
    );
    console.log('after');
  }
  return (
    <Button
      title="Test"
      onPress={submit}
    />
  );
}
```

the only thing I see in the console is:

```
submit
after
```

I've tried `Axios` as well and it's the same results.

This issue happens for both Android and IOS...

---

*EDIT*

Just tried using the `XMLHttpRequest` api, and again, only `submit` logs:

```
function submit() {
  console.log('submit');
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    console.log('ready', e);
    if (request.readyState !== 4) {
      return;
    }
    if (request.status === 200) {
      console.log('success', request.responseText);
    } else {
      console.warn('error');
    }
  };
  request.open('GET', 'https://swapi.co/api/people/1/');
  request.send();
}
```

Comment: please try `<Button title="Test" onClick={submit}/>` instead of `onPress`

Comment: `onPress` is the correct prop: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button - but regardless of how the function is called, I'm looking for insight on how to get fetch working...

Comment: Do you see submit in log?

Comment: @behzad yeah, only `submit` logs

Comment: Can you use axios and try again?

Comment: @behzad as stated in the question, I've tried `axios` as well, and it's the same problem

Comment: Sorry didnt see your bottom text, hmmm i recommend 2 way, 1, close all of your apps and re run and build again, it may fix it (happend for me few times ) , second, instead of regular function use helper method or  arrow function, if you want i can give you a sample

Comment: is your `console.log('submit'); ` working?

Comment: Use https://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json

Comment: @behzad I reset my computer, rebuilt, and I'm still seeing the same issues - @Sandeep Sudhakaran - please see my comments above - @Joseph D. - the problem isn't the API - the `submit` function works fine when I drop it in a web project

Comment: So would you try change your regular function to helper method? It may help

Comment: I tried to re-create your code on sandbox but on react js instead of react-native and everything works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-30i5l Can you add your package json in your question?

Comment: oh wait have you done `import react from "react"`?

Comment: @behzad - the `submit` function is being called just fine - changing it to an arrow function or declaring the function elsewhere has no effect on it - @Atin Singh - `fetch` is part of react-native, it should work regardless of how my package.json is setup

Answer (score 1):

How about `onPress={() => this.submit()}`

Comment: `onPress` is the correct prop: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button#onpress - regardless of how the `submit` function is called, the problem is that `fetch` doesn't seem to fire

Comment: `this.submit` is undefined as it is a functional component hence only `onPress={()=> submit()}` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

original code

```
function submit() {
    console.log('submit');
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/').then(
      res => {
        console.log('res', res);
        return res.json();
      },
      err => console.log('err', err)
    ).then(
      res => console.log('res', res)
    ).catch(
      err => console.log('catch', err)
    ).finally(
      res => console.log('finally', res)
    );
    console.log('after');
  }
```

Modify as follows

```
async function submit() {
    console.log('submit');

    await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(resJson => console.log('res ', resJson))
        .catch(err => console.log('catch ', err))
        .finally(() => console.log('finally'));

    console.log('after');
}
```

So the following results are in the console:

```
submit
res {name: "Luke Skywalker", height: "172", mass: "77", hair_color: "blond", skin_color: "fair", …}
finally
after
```